# ctrl is still pressed even after the program is terminated

Tags: c++, winapi

I create an algorithm that copies some data from one file and pastes it into the program.
To copy this data I use this:

```
keybd_event (VK_CONTROL, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
sleep (500);
keybd_event (VK_CONTROL, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
keybd_event (0x43, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
Sleep (1);
keybd_event (0x43, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

Everything works fine, but after I stop the program, ctrl is still pressed and I have to reset my pc to turn it off. I tried to change the order but still nothing.

```
keybd_event (VK_CONTROL, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
keybd_event (0x43, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
sleep (500);
keybd_event (VK_CONTROL, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
Sleep (1);
keybd_event (0x43, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Are you using some library for these functions i.e. `keybd_event`, etc.?

Comment: I am using <windows.h>

Comment: How does `sleep` and `Sleep` both work?

Comment: Look a the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-keybd_event).

Comment: If you use KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY for keydown then you have to use it as well for keyup.  So KEYEVENTF_KEYUP | KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY.  But note that VK_CONTROL is not an extended key, only Right-Ctrl is.

Comment: What are those random `Sleep` calls supposed to accomplish? It's also wildly unclear how simulating keyboard input and copying data between processes are somehow related. Maybe you should explain the **problem** you are trying to solve rather than ask about your solution. I'm pretty convinced that this is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: If you are trying to stimulate `Ctrl-C`, you need to put `Ctrl` into the down state and keep it there while putting `C` down, then release `C`, then release `Ctrl`. Also, `keybd_event()` is long deprecated, use `SendInput()` instead, and get rid of the sleeps entirely.